# Concat two video files with fade effect using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to concat two video files with a fading effect using FFmpeg?

Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy "--with:fade:out-in" output.ogg
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your present command specifies stream copy. Since you wish to alter the video frames during the transition, that won't work.

It can be done if you know the duration of the two videos and the duration of fade. Also, for the command below, the resolutions of the two videos should be the same.

```
ffmpeg -i first.ogg -i second.ogg \
-filter_complex \
"color=black:WxH:d=Video1Length+Video2Length-FadeDuration[base]; \
 [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=FadeDuration:alpha=1, \
      setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((Video1Length-FadeDuration)/TB)[v1]; \
 [base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
 [tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[fv]; \
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=FadeDuration[fa]" \
-map [fv] -map [fa] \
output.ogg
```

Replace:

`WxH` with the resolution of the videos i.e. `640x360`

And:

`Video1Length`, `Video2Length`, and `FadeDuration` with their value in seconds.

Comment: what about adding a third, fourth, or nth video? I conceptualize this by running the above on first.ogg and second.ogg, producing output1.ogg. Then I would run the script with output1.ogg and third.ogg to get output2.ogg (and so on up to output[n-1].ogg). Is this efficient or is there a better way to do it all at once?

Comment: I tried to use "ffmpeg-gl-transition" and followed all instruction for my mac. The transition works. However, I loose audio on my second video for some reason. My command was: fmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "gltransition=duration=4:source=ZoomInCircles.glsl" -y out.mp4

Comment: Why would you overlay the first video over a black screen? It looks like waste of resources as it does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

[ffmpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat) is the easiest way to accomplish what you want and allows you to use a bunch of sexy OpenGL transitions, with the default being crossfade.

[ffmpeg-gl-transition](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition) is a custom ffmpeg filter which allows you to use GLSL to smoothly transition between two video streams. This filter is significantly easier to use and customize than the alternatives listed here.

This filter supports a large [list](https://gl-transitions.com/) of transition types, with the default being crossfade.

```
./ffmpeg -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "gltransition=duration=4:offset=1.5" out.mp4
```

Comment: Have you submitted this to ffmpeg-devel for integration?

Comment: Official patch will be coming soon :)

Comment: @fisch2 Any updates?

Comment: Note, ffmpeg-concat requires Python.

Comment: I installed Python on my Mac, but still it raise many error when installing `ffmpeg-concat`

Answer (score 4):

I've created a little site recently for generating the FFmpeg CLI command to create xfade + acrossfade command for several videos. Check it out maybe you find it useful.

https://romander.github.io/ffmpeg-script-generator/

Add also you can check source code or contribute

https://github.com/Romander/ffmpeg-script-generator

Comment: This is a great idea but it doesn't seem to produce working code. [This](https://pastebin.com/sMhzCKL1) is what I get after entering two inputs.

Comment: @HashimAziz  Do you really input everything correct it should look like that [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ZUEQMcF), sorry for the inconvenient UI

Comment: @RomanOgoreltsev I have tried and find that your website is very helpful. Thanks a lot!